# gestureResponseDistance does not work in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a Sheets type modal in ReactNative, but I can't close the screen with a swipe gesture because gestureResponseDistance doesn't work.
The code looks like the following, but what is causing it to not work?

**Example of not responding to any part of the screen**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={globalScreenOptions}>
    <Stack.Screen name="TestPage" component={TestPage} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Setting"
      component={Setting}
      options={{
        ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
        cardOverlayEnabled: true,
        gestureEnabled: true,
        gestureResponseDistance: {
          vertical: 800,
        },
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;
```

**Example of only one part of the upper part of the screen responding**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={globalScreenOptions}>
    <Stack.Screen name="TestPage" component={TestPage} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Setting"
      component={Setting}
      options={{
        ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
        cardOverlayEnabled: true,
        gestureEnabled: true,
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;
```

The code is somewhat abbreviated.

After trying various things, it seems that adding `gestureResponseDistance` makes it unresponsive, but how can I make it so that the modal closes no matter where I swipe on the screen?

I'm a foreigner and I'm using a translation, so the language may be a little strange, but I would appreciate it if you could tell me more about it.

**vartion**

"react": "17.0.1",

"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0",

"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.0",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of [gestureResponseDistance](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) is a **number** not an **object**

In your case it should be

```
gestureResponseDistance: 800
```